# Finding relative ordering of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, order

Suppose you have two lists `A` and `B` which are related by a permutation, and have no repeated elements.

Is there a simple and efficient way of finding the ordering `p` which satisfies `A[[p]]==B`?

The best I have is

```
p = First@FirstPosition[A,#]&/@B;
```

However, this seems inefficient as it neglects much of the structure of the problem. I imagined there might be a way of using `OrderingBy` but I couldn't see a way to easily employ it, as it takes a function, rather than a canonical order, as its argument.

Comment: `p = OrderingBy[A, Position[B, #] &]`

Comment: `A[[PermutationList@FindPermutation[B, A]]]==B`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can use

```
p = Permute[Ordering[A],Ordering[B]];
```

**Example.** Here is an example of length 100000:

```
A=RandomReal[{-1,1},100000];
B=RandomSample[A];
RepeatedTiming[p = Permute[Ordering[A],Ordering[B]];]
(* about 0.015 seconds *)
```

Comment: This seems to be the fastest solution by a reasonable margin. Thank you!

Comment: @ComptonScattering Are your list using numbers, or words, or other type of expressions?

Comment: @AntonAntonov In my particular case each element is a length two list of integers.

Comment: Ok, then the code of this answer is faster than the code in mine. :) (That is not the case if the elements are strings.)

Answer (score 5):

This might be too contrived (first thing that came to mind), but seems to work:

````mathematica
SeedRandom[33];
A = RandomWord[5]
B = RandomSample[A];

(* {"scrooge", "candelabra", "together", "jotting", "remorseful"} *)

{aA, aB} = AssociationThread[#, Range[Length[#]]] & /@ {A, B}

(* {<|"scrooge" -> 1, "candelabra" -> 2, "together" -> 3, 
  "jotting" -> 4, "remorseful" -> 5|>, <|"scrooge" -> 1, 
  "candelabra" -> 2, "jotting" -> 3, "remorseful" -> 4, 
  "together" -> 5|>} *)

A[[Values[KeyTake[aA, Keys[aB]]]]] == B

(* True *)
```
````

Answer (score 4):

`FindPermutation` almost does this but it gives the output in terms of Cycles. The name is easy to remember if needed for later use but it is slower than the fastest method here (two times slower than the method in @293787's answer with the test list given in that answer). If you would like the ordering as a list then :

```
Permute[Range[Length[A]], FindPermutation[A, B]]
```

Answer (score 2):

We may create the permutation that changes A to B by:

```
perm = (Position[B, #][[1, 1]]) & /@ A
```

With "perm", we can now permute A into B:

```
Permute[A, perm]
```

Comment: But this is not significantly faster than OPs code. Try to apply this when `A=RandomReal[{-1,1},100000]; B=RandomSample[A];` for example. I think OP specifically asks for more efficient code.

Answer (score 2):

Using Anton Antonov's data

```
SeedRandom[33];

a = RandomWord[5]
```

> {"scrooge", "candelabra", "together", "jotting", "remorseful"}

```
b = RandomSample[a]
```

> {"scrooge", "candelabra", "jotting", "remorseful", "together"}

```
p = Flatten @ Values @ KeyTake[MapIndexed[Rule, a], b]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 5, 3}

```
Extract[a, List /@ p] == b
```

> True